# Sub-sites can't access to style library

Tags: 2013, style-library

I have got a site and multiple sub-sites under it. The problem I'm having is that all the JS files are located in Style Library of the master site, and users who don't have access to master site getting access denied errors.

I'm guessing this might be related to sub-sites don't have direct access to the Style Library of the master, but I'm not sure. (I'm not even sure whether this makes sense or not, I'm a newbie.)

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Typically the Style Resources Reader group has restricted read to the root style library. This group contains all authenticated users by default. First check to see if this group exists on the library and does have the all authenticated users in it.

Second, check to make sure all of your assets are checked in as major versions and approved if necessary.

If all of these are correct, you could alter the Style Resources Readers group to have read permission on the library.

Comment: For some reason I don't have Style Resources Reader group under People and Groups. Fixed my issue by giving permission to user groups I want to Style Library.

Comment: 'Restricted Read' wasn'r enough in my case. Created and granted "Contribute (no delete)" permission level.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by following this [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18162.sharepoint-2013-document-library-permissions.aspx).

I have set special permissions for the groups that require access to master's Style Library. To do that I had to stop inheriting permissions.